# How to detect "resource preloaded but not used" warning in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, preload

Is there a way to listen for the `resource preloaded but not used` warning in Chrome? I'm trying to send these events to my analytics platform via client side javascript.

I’ve tried overriding `console.warn` but it doesn’t appear to be sent using that function.